# Array initialized redundant zeros while printing binary tree paths

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I have trying print all paths from in a binary tree. I am able to print all paths in the tree. but the problem is its not printing some redundant zeros in the output. Does arrays get initialized with zeros ? if yes then how to overcome the problem in the case like this ? I am learning and thats why I have posted this question here to learn more and overcome errors.

```
public class PrintAllPath {

static void printAllPaths(Tree tree) {
    int[] paths = new int[1000];
    printPathsRecur(tree, paths, 0);
}

static void printPathsRecur(Tree tree, int paths[], int pathlen) {
    if (tree == null)
        return;
    paths[pathlen++] = tree.val;
    pathlen++;

    if (tree.left == null && tree.right == null) {
        printArray(paths, pathlen);
    } else {
        printPathsRecur(tree.left, paths, pathlen);
        printPathsRecur(tree.right, paths, pathlen);
    }
}

static void printArray(int paths[], int pathlen) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pathlen; i++) {
        System.out.println("Node : " + paths[i]);
    }
}

static Tree insert(Tree tree, int element) {
    Tree tree2 = new Tree(element, null, null);
    if (tree == null)
        tree = tree2;
    else if (element < tree.val)
        tree.left = insert(tree.left, element);
    else
        tree.right = insert(tree.right, element);
    return tree;
}

static void print(Tree tree) {
    if (tree == null)
        return;
    System.out.println(tree.val);
    print(tree.left);
    print(tree.right);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tree tree = new Tree(new Integer(5), null, null);
    tree = insert(tree, 10);
    tree = insert(tree, 100);
    tree = insert(tree, 11);
    tree = insert(tree, 110);
    tree = insert(tree, 50);
    System.out.println("The tree is as follows : ");
    print(tree);
    printAllPaths(tree);
}
}
```

Ouput :

```
The tree is as follows : 
5
10
100
11
50
110
5 0 10 0 100 0 11 0 50 0 5 0 10 0 100 0 110 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in Java, `new int[X]` creates a zero-initialized array.

From [JLS §4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10) ... For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0.

Anyway, the reason you're getting zeros is because you increment `pathlen` *twice* every time you insert an element, so you insert an element and then skip the next element (leaving it at 0):

```
paths[pathlen++] = tree.val;
pathlen++;
```

You only have to increment once.

Comment: yes, i think paths[pathlen++] = tree.val; was not required. only paths[pathlen] = tree.val; was enough

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing pathlen twice. Remove the second pathlen++. Yes, Java will initialize all primitives to default values, including those in arrays.

Comment: Not just primitives: everything is initialized. Reference types just get `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you made is in `printPathsRecur(Tree tree, int paths[], int pathlen)`

```
paths[pathlen++] = tree.val;
pathlen++;
```

**you increase pathlen by two**. only removing `pathlen++;` from your code works fine.

```
static void printPathsRecur(Tree tree, int paths[], int pathlen) {
    if (tree == null)
        return;
    paths[pathlen++] = tree.val;
    //pathlen++;

    if (tree.left == null && tree.right == null) {
        printArray(paths, pathlen);
    } else {
        printPathsRecur(tree.left, paths, pathlen);
        printPathsRecur(tree.right, paths, pathlen);
    }
}
```